# Inject a sub query into Criteria query

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

This method:

```
  public List<User> exampleForSO(int size, int page, boolean name, boolean email) {

        Criteria criteria = getSession().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);

        if (name) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotEmpty("name"));
        }

        if (email) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotEmpty("email"));
        }

        criteria.setMaxResults(size);
        criteria.setFirstResult(page);

        List<User> users = criteria.list();

        return users;
    }
```

Produces the following SQL:

```
Hibernate: select this_.name as y0_, this_.id as y1_ from users this_ where this_.id is not null limit ? offset ?
```

How could I achieve this query  ?

```
Hibernate: select this_.name as y0_, this_.id as y1_, COUNT(*) OVER() as overallCount from users this_ where this_.id is not null limit ? offset ?
```

Basically I want to add this little line into the query:

```
COUNT(*) OVER() as overallCount
```

Any suggestions ?

Could this be solved with a DetachedCriteria ?

What I have tried:

1. Create a DetachedCriteria and add it as a sub query to the actual Criteria query, this is not an option, I don't want a sub query.
2. Generate a RawSQL String and try to inject it into the query, without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone is trying to achieve the same.

This is how I did it:

I created a field in my User class like so:

```
@Formula("COUNT(*) OVER()")
private Long overallCount;
```

You can read more about [Hibernate Formula Annotation here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-column)